# Displaying panel after p:ajax update does not work

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have a panel which is collapsed when first opening the page and should get updated with an p:ajax attached to a selectOneButton

```
<p:selectOneButton required="true"
    value="#{bean.jobProfile.salary.subjectToDisclosure}"
    id="salarySubjectToDisclosure">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}" itemLabel="#{msg['yes']}" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}" itemLabel="#{msg['no']}" />
    <p:ajax
        listener="#{bean.changeSubjectToDisclosure()}"
        update="@(.paymentDetailsSliderHeaderUpdateable) grossPaymentWrapper" />
</p:selectOneButton>
```

So. There are 2 options. Yes and No. On yes the panel with the id grossPaymentWrapper should get displayed and on no collapsed.

The panel:

```
<p:panel id="grossPaymentWrapper">
    #{!bean.jobProfile.salary.subjectToDisclosure}
    <p:panel toggleable="true"
                collapsed="#{!bean.jobProfile.salary.subjectToDisclosure}">
```

The line `#{!bean.jobProfile.salary.subjectToDisclosure}` always gets updated displaying true or false when selecting a different button, but the panel is not visible for both options.

Help is appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the attribute `toggleable="true"` of the inner `p:panel` component?

The documentation of the p:panel component describes the collapsed attribute as

> "Renders a toggleable panel as collapsed. Default is false."

Link to documentation: http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/6.0/core/primefaces-p/panel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript, Primfaces p:panel have a JavaScript function called `toggle()`, you can call be by adding a `widgetVar` to your `p:panel`, the call the `toggle` function on that component.

```
<p:panel id="..." widgetVar="panel">
...
</p:panel>
```

and then use : `PF('panel').toggle()`